# how to minify multiple js files in multiple directories into one js locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, uglifyjs

I want to minify multiple javascript files where those files in multiple directories.

I tried gulp uglify and grunt uglify. But those things just minify one file at a time.

http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-the-task-runner-gulp

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you should concatenate the files firstly (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#usage-examples) then you run the grunt uglify.

Comment: So, in that case, you can use the Play Framework to minify your javascript files: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Assets#The-Assets-controller

`Play 2.0 comes with a built-in controller to serve public assets. By default, this controller provides caching, ETag, gzip compression and **JavaScript minification support**.`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Minify](https://github.com/mrclay/minify) on GitHub. It allows for you to combine multiple JS files into one by stacking them into a URL. Have not used it myself, but it seems pretty reliable from other users reviews and posts on Stackoverflow. May be worth a look:)

Comment: Yes, I believe it does, the server in which the program is installed on requires PHP 5 as a requirement. Apart from that, I only think the back-end part of the program uses PHP, I think everything else is URL based for control. Still, the GitHub page looks pretty detailed if you wanted to set it up:)

Comment: i need something which can do it by using javascript